# Why I've gotten "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'counter' of undefined" despite I'm using arrow function for SetTimeout?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, settimeout, arrow-functions

The following small count down application cause **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'counter' of undefined** at the timing of evaluation of this.counter.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      Redirect after {{counter}} sec.
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
/* eslint-disable no-console */
export default {
  name: 'App',

  components: {
  },
  mounted() {
    this.countdown();
  },
  created() {
  },
  methods: {
    countdown: () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (--this.counter <=0){
          location.href=this.$redirectURL;
        } else {
          this.countdown();
        }
      }, 1*1000);
    }
  },

  data: () => ({
    counter: 5,
  }),
};
</script>
```

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'counter' of undefined** as follows:

[image]

I have no idea why **coutner** is evaluated as **undefined** despite I'm using arrow function, which means the scope of "**this** pointer" must be lexical. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: Beacuse `this` in your script refers `undefined`.There's no context where you define the arrow function  (modules are always in strict mode).

Comment: Thanks Teemu! I see, this function has no context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `countdown` function is an arrow function, which means that the `this` inside it is inherited from the outer scope. The same is true for the `setTimeout` callback. So, here:

```
export default {
  // ...
  methods: {
    countdown: () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (--this.counter <=0){
          location.href=this.$redirectURL;
        } else {
          this.countdown();
        }
      }, 1*1000);
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

`this` refers to the `this` at the top level of the module, which is `undefined` in your setup.

You want `this` to refer to the current instance instead: when calling `countdown`, it should *capture* the new `this` value (of the instance), rather than inheriting the `this` of the outer scope. So, change:

```
countdown: () => {
```

to

```
countdown() {
```

or to

```
countdown: function() {
```